# User Independant Share Folder

Tags: permissions, samba, users

At the moment, I have a folder in my home directory that is shared on my laptop and can also be accessed by the other windows desktop pcs in my network but now I have decided to make my home folder inaccessible by other users on my laptop so other people cannot look at my files if they have a user on my laptop. I set the permissions to none for everyone apart from me. I then changed the share folder (/home/elliot/Shared) to allow all access but my windows computers and other users on my laptop cannot access it even though they have the right permission, I think this is because they don't have access to the home folder in which the Shared folder is stored.

Where should I store a new Shared folder on my laptop? Should I put it as /home/Shared? Or, alternatively is there a way I can allow other users to access my /home/elliot/Shared folder even if /home/elliot is inaccessible?

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the folder permissions of Shared to all and create a symbolic link in `/home`. This would allow others to access your shared folder. Here is how you do it:

```
sudo ln -s /home/elliot/Shared /home
```

Comment: Okay, thanks :) Do you think /home is the most appropriate place to store this? I think if I'm putting it in home I will just move the whole folder